# libspotify API: play track from a certain time spot?

Tags: spotify

Is there any way to start playing a track from a certain time spot? I found this old [hints & tips](http://www.spotify.com/int/blog/archives/2009/06/12/hints-tips-%E2%80%93-link-to-a-specific-track-time/), but didn't work when I tried it in libspotify program. Any update on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear. What platform are you developing for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In libSpotify, you need to start playing the track, then immediately seek to the offset you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have read the API document more thoroughly. One more API question - Is the callback **end_of_track**  triggered when **sp_session_player_unload** is called to stop a track? The document says **end_of_track** is called when the currently played track has reached its end, but if the track is stopped in the middle, will it get called as well?

Comment: Don't think so — why don't you try it and see?